# DAL and BLL in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, data-access-layer, bll

There is this [DAL/BLL design suggestion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288041.aspx) by Microsoft for ASP.NET (2.0) apps. I know some of the alternatives and I've read related questions here on SO. However I wonder if this proposed solution is worth implementing nowadays, is there a specific downside you know of?

I want to develop DAL/BLL components for company-internal use, to access customer and employee data, etc from various applications and scripts. However before I start building that stuff, I want to be sure that this solution is 'good'. As example, the [BLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581779.aspx) passes datatables instead of encapsulating anything, you don't have isolated business objects that contain logic. It's basically only a dumb layer that eases the CRUD operations a bit and allows databinding for controls.

Could someone, who has experience in this field, point me out the pro's and con's of this approach?

Comment: You can develop both BAL and DAl using following link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/paulabraham/Building3TierAppPA11282005053625AM/Building3TierAppPA.aspx Where source code,demo and explanation are given

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**pros:**

- simple approach and some of the data mapping is done for you with the datatable's.

- offers some conveniences for firing Select, Add, Update and Delete queries.

- might be suitable for very simple design with few tables.

- suitable for non-self-referencing ER degigns or ER's with few lookup tables and simple/few joins

- suitable where simple data store is required. ie. where complex OO ideas should be applied to the "business objects" this pattern would make things more difficult.

**cons:**

- large OO models will struggle in this pattern

- complex ER designs with many tables, complex relationships or OO object requirements will not fit this pattern. the datatables dont provide much assistance for in-code object querying like LINQ.

- most queries need to be written by hand in SQL (this includes joins). yes, you can use the query designer, but this dont help much.

- there is a lot of code duplication in this approach. as in you will write lots of CRUD methods in your BLL classes (which you also need to write from scratch).

**conclusion:**
it really depends on your requirements. if your implementation is small/simple then this might be a good idea. but growing on a small idea will be hard with this approach. a more OO approach will set you up much better for refactoring/expanding later.
this pattern is also older/antiquated. object querying IQueryable/LINQ is more popular and will become a wider standard shortly. i'd suggest u jump on board this wagon. it will be better for your personal development in the long run too. :D

**some links:**

- try aspnet MVC - http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-360.aspx?redir=true
- http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-361.aspx?redir=true
- http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-395.aspx
- if your scope is bigger, this will be a good start with handy patterns - http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-350.aspx

Answer (score 12):

I fully recommend NOT USING DATATABLES. Look into a domain driven design implementation that your entire framework will work with regular objects that you can pass into List<> or Queryable<>. DataTables are garbage that shouldn't even be included in .NET anymore.

I would also recommend looking into using a Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control framework such Microsoft Unity or StructureMap to create loosely coupled code.

Comment: i agree but not to the extent that DataTables should not be included in .NET. they still belong to the System.Data namespace and are useful for creating fast demo apps using data from databases. Look at the brighter side of this object. :-P

Comment: @jerbersoft they should be deprecated atleast.